# Keep the master menu instead of up button

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is it somehow possible to keep the master menu icon / hamburger icon instead of getting the back / up arrow when I navigate? The user is already able to navigate back through the System Button and the one in the navigation page is totally obsolete.

ps. I‘m not interested in NavigationPage in NavigationPage solutions because this isn’t a solution it’s just a bad style workaround.

Comment: please provide code for what you have did so far

Comment: How exactly should Code help there? I‘m not having a solution. I‘m not even sure how to focus on that if you search for it you only get the NavigationPage within NavigationPage Bullshit. It’s pretty simple to implement something like this to iOS but this won’t work on Android. But I know it must be possible because the Amazon app has done it.

Comment: I guess you could use fragments or custom views instead of using activities. That way you would have activity with toolbar that contains hamburger icon no matter what and your content would be contained in fragments or custom views.

Comment: That would not be possible due to the usage of Xamarin.Forms with MvvmCross. And actual I don't understand why there is not just a simple property to disable the back / up button. Who needs this button anyway if you can use the system button all the time for it?

Comment: how will you go back in ios then by sliding back and what if the user doesnt know its native behaviour of page slide back @Sebastian

Comment: iOS can add both buttons at the same time (Back + Master Menu) while this is not necessary on Android because every device has a back button (but I would also take this solution if I know how todo it...)